# MongoDB stops working after some time

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I have installed MongoDB 3.2 into my Ubuntu 16.04 server.
At the beginning work but after some time it stops working giving this error :

```
E QUERY [thread1] Error : network error while attempting to run command 'isMaster' on host '127.0.0.1:27017'
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:229:14
@(connect):1:6

exception: connect failed
```

I already tried the solutions proposed in some forums but have not worked.

Comment: Is the mongod process running (you can figure it out with a command like `pgrep mongod`)?

Comment: now is running, when it will stop working i will try

Comment: yes the mongo process is running : http://prntscr.com/d1lq3z

Comment: Can you recall what changes had been made on your box before it stopped working (network configuration etc.)?

Comment: I think not, no one uses it, it disconnects alone. Since the mongo service continues to run I believe the problem is the mongo shell

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

just try and close your connections after using mongo with all apps accessing mongo. worked for me. you can verify this by checking your log at /var/log/mongodb